# add time to filename in batch file

Tags: batch-file

Hi I have a batch file that runs a couple of programs to screenshot some of my webpages.

looks like this

```
@echo off
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('echo %date%')
do (
set DDMMYYYY=%%a%%b%%c
)

webscreencapture.exe http://123.com c:/users/d/desktop/dealscreens/folder1/!DDMMYYYY!.jpg
webscreencapture.exe http://1234.com c:/users/d/desktop/folder2/!DDMMYYYY!.jpg
```

This worked fine for capturing screens once per day, but now I am wanting to capture screens twice per day, so I need a time or similar added to the filenames so I get two screenshots name differently.

Answer (score 0):

try this - I haven't tested it but it should be close.

```
@echo off 
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion 
for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('echo %date%') 
do (
  set DDMMYYYY=%%a%%b%%c
)

for /f "tokens=1-5 delims=:" %%d in ("%time%") 
do (
  set HHMM=%%d%%e 
)
```

And then:

```
webscreencapture.exe 
  http://123.com 
  c:/users/d/desktop/dealscreens/folder1/!DDMMYYYY!!HHMM!.jpg
```

[NOTE: The above should be a single line as you have it already. I put it on multiple lines to make it easier to read.]

Comment: Appreciate your help Kevin. The batch file will not execute with the new code

Comment: I believe the basic info you need is in the file. You'll need to work through the details to get it working I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

### Add the time

You probably should add the time to the filename. The hour should be enough - unless you use am/pm and your script executes for example at 1 am and 1 pm.

Unfortunately, date and time formats depend on the regional settings. If you know what the date and time regional settings are, this will be easier and shorter.

Rob van der Woude has a complete writeup of this topic on his site:
http://www.robvanderwoude.com/datetimentbasics.php and http://www.robvanderwoude.com/datetime.php, with different approaches and scripts.

### Add a counter

It may be easier to add a suffix to the file name and increment it each time.

For example:

```
@echo off
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('echo %date%')
do (
set DDMMYYYY=%%a%%b%%c
)

SET /a c=1
:checkfilename
IF EXISTS c:/users/d/desktop/dealscreens/folder1/!DDMMYYYY!-!c!.jpg (
    SET /a c=!c!+1
    GOTO :checkfilename
)

webscreencapture.exe http://123.com c:/users/d/desktop/dealscreens/folder1/!DDMMYYYY!-!c!.jpg
webscreencapture.exe http://1234.com c:/users/d/desktop/folder2/!DDMMYYYY!-!c!.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

set the Tokens to 1-4 and NOT 2-4, then it will show you the output in DDMMYYY